# Pure CSS Parallax effect issue

Tags: css, parallax

seem to be having issues with my pure css parallax, im using the concept from [this](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) article. However this doesn't seem to be working for me at all.

Am I going about it all wrong?

You can inspect my code using a debugger [here](http://martynleeball.com/mps/).

**Edit:**
Sorry I though providing the link would let you inspect the code easier rather than read and try and understand pasted code snippets.

I want to have parallax effects on sections of my website.

Here you can see my HTML, there are more parts but im currently trying to get my header working with a parallax scrolling background:

```
<body class="parallax">
<header class="parallax__group">
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back darken"></div>

  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base flex alignvcenter">
    <div id="hdr-logo">
      <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="Mobile Paint Solutions" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div id="hdr-hint">
      <img src="" alt="" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div id="hdr-nav">
      <nav>
        <a href=""><span>Home</span></a>
        <a href=""><span>About</span></a>
        <a href=""><span>Gallery</span></a>
        <a href=""><span>Reviews</span></a>
        <a href=""><span>Pricing</span></a>
        <a href=""><span>Contact</span></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

And here are my **LESS** styles:

```
    .parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
.parallax__layer--deep {
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}
```

However currently the background is not moving at all, can anyone explain this?

Comment: There are two major problems with your question and, given your reputation, I would have expected you knew them: A) The moment you solve the issue on the linked website, the question loses relevance, hence ceasing to help future visitors having the same problem. [so] is about helping OP ***and all subsequent visitors*** with same problem. If this is only about solving your specific problem, you're probably on the wrong website. B) To answer, one would have to exclude irrelevant parts of code (create [mcve]). You are by far the most appropriate person to do it. Please improve your question.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: I appreciate it, @MartynBall. Removed my down-vote. Could you please replace `LESS` with [resulting `CSS`](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler)?

Comment: Shoutout to OP my homie who said my solution is not working, http://i.imgur.com/rV1CDho.png

Comment: lol @Dražen didn't say it didnt work, I said thats NOT parallax

Comment: Do you know what parallax is?

Comment: @Dražen That's not really parallax, or at least not the KIND of parallax i'm after. Modern day parallax is where the background moves slower than the foreground so it looks further away: Parallax is a displacement or difference in the apparent position of an object viewed along two different lines of sight, and is measured by the angle or semi-angle of inclination between those two lines.

Comment: @Dražen if you read my post, there is a link showing the effect I wanted to achieve. Im not trying to be a `jerk`, I was trying to explain that what you posted had no research in terms of reading my post correctly (i.e, following the desired effect link) but you insisted that you was correct -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason the effect (`parallax` or not) does not work is because you used `<body>` as the host element. Probably some of the properties it uses have no effect on `<body>`. I assume we're talking `perspective` and its vendor prefixed counterparts.

The obvious fix is to use a `<div>` as host, not `<body>`. I tried to use some styles and images from the website you linked, but it doesn't look too good. You got the idea though.

Comment: Im assuming Dražen downvoted you so my upvote cancelled that out. What you posted doesn't appear to work for some reason however adding a div instead of using the body does help, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy coding! I don't mind the down-vote. I do hope my comments here have been helpful for a few folks. At least that was my intention.

Comment: @Dražen sorry to hear the time I invested into comments for you was a waste. It happens.

Comment: No, I said I downvoted Martyn only. @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: Uh, ok, well, it doesn't matter. I'm not after the points. I'm after helping people out. I hope I was helpful for both of you. Take care! (P.S.: @Dražen There's a card on that gift. It reads: don't answer low quality questions anymore! Ask the OP to improve them first).

Answer (score -3):

Adding

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

to your

```
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back darken"></div>
```

or actually class named

```
parallax__layer--back
```

fixed the thing.

**Edit:** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaD6n.png) this works, gentleman.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is.

Comment: @Dražen, I am one of the down-voters and I did not even check to see if it works or not. I think your answer encourages other users to post low quality questions. Please read [answer] and you will notice you are encouraged to only answer well researched questions. This question shows no research effort. If you care about reputation, you'll get it back by either deleting the answer or from the upvote/accepted answer from the OP, if your solution actually works. But you should expect down-votes when answering low quality questions.

Comment: @Dražen I am one of the downvotes. You answer reflects how to fix the position of a background not how to perform genuine parallax. Your method provides only a fixed background image and cannot be used for any other purpose. IT certainly does not answer the question.